# Accessing BIOS to start computer automatically

Tags: batch-file, cmd, bios

I'm interested in starting up my computer before I get to work because we HAVE TO shut it down at the end of the day (I.T manager insists), and it takes forever to start-up.

Ideally I would like my computer to switch itself on at 630am.  It takes me a half hour to get to work (15 mins to start-up/ includes kixtart script which runs at start-up).

It's taken me some time but I have figured out how to time my bios to wake up using the Power ON / RESUME By Alarm method, this has to be done manually. Only I like everything programmatically. I also know that I'm able to touch base with my BIOS using batch and CMD including with help of the debug option.

Hence its not entirely strange then (according to me) if I could then program the computer to start-up using batch to set the Power ON / RESUME By Alarm method.

Dose anyone know how to achieve this, as my limit is sort of at this level of programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is to utilise a Wake-on-LAN utlity - there are lots available

Comment: nope it seams i can only get limited information about my bios, i can always do it the manualy way.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter BISO Setup utility by F1/F2 or Del key(I don't know which PC are you used)
Then you can enter Power sub-menu, it should have a function to set auto power-on by weekly/ daily(I used ThinkCentre have this feature).